# Can not access API for Bandsintown Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to access data from Bandsintown. I am using their Gem and have followed their instructions on their github page.

Though, their is a problem that I cannot solve. I can't access an artists events without getting an error.

If I only return the Artist object, the response will be a Bandsintown-object like this:

```
    <Bandsintown::Artist:0x007fc5d8f1be90  @name="kanyewest", @mbid=nil, @bandsintown_url="http://www.bandsintown.com/kanyewest">
```

And that object comes from this code which I have this in my controller -

```
@artist = Bandsintown::Artist.new({
  :name => "Kanye West"
})
@events = artist.events
```

But if I want to access an artists events using their method, it won't work. I will get an error that says:

```
undefined method `returning' for Bandsintown::Event:Class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us what do you do with events after @events = artist.events ?

Comment: I use the variable in the ruby console in my view. But that gives me the error...

Comment: Show the code using it.

Comment: I use this in my view:  
    `<% @events.each do |e| %><%= e %>
<% end %>`
Thank you for taking your time!